# DNS unable to resolve canonical hostname

Tags: apache, http, solr, server, dns

I'm unable to solve the below error since hours in Solr Admin. Please help me.

Unable to resolve canonical hostname for local host,​ possible DNS misconfiguration. Set the 'solr.dns.prevent.reverse.lookup' sysprop to true on startup to prevent future lookups if DNS can not be fixed.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting `solr.dns.prevent.reverse.lookup` to true?

Comment: Could you please tell me where to make this modification? I'm new to Solr. I did not find the SystemInfoHandler file anywhere

Comment: Depending on how you're starting Solr, you can edit `solr.in.cmd` (windows) or `solr.in.sh` in Linux. Search for `SOLR_OPTS` and see how it uses `-D...` parameters to set new values. `-Dsolr.dns.prevent.reverse.lookup=true` is what you'd add as a setting like this. Fixing DNS would be to make sure that `localhost` resolves locally at least - I'm not sure what the actual test is, but that can be looked up on github if necessary.

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you so much!!! You are my savior!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The standard JVM accepts `-D<param name>=<value>` to set global configuration values available to the running application.

Depending on how you're starting Solr, you can edit solr.in.cmd in Windows or solr.in.sh in Linux or OS X.

Search for `SOLR_OPTS` and see how it uses `-D...` parameters to set new values. `-Dsolr.dns.prevent.reverse.lookup=true` is what you'd add as a setting like this.

Fixing DNS would be to make sure that localhost resolves locally at least.

Answer (score 0):

The most direct way to fix this issue is to start Solr with the system property `solr.dns.prevent.reverse.lookup=true` in the command line.

For instance under Windows in a PowerShell console :

```
bin\solr.cmd start "-Dsolr.dns.prevent.reverse.lookup=true"
```